# Find out usage statistics of MySQL indices?

Tags: mysql, indexing, statistics, usage-statistics

Is it possible to find out how often an index of a MySQL table was used?

I have several indices for a table and I'd like to find out, if there are indice which are not used by MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***NOTE: This answer is no longer valid as of 5.5.3!***

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43205887/1251127

*Original answer below.*

Currently, MySQL does not offer statistics on index usage.

One way to generate those stats on your own would be to log all queries (Be careful of the extra i/o here) and parse it out. Percona has a nice tool for this, [pt-index-usage](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-index-usage.html).

Comment: That's too bad, I share the exact same need.

Answer (score 52):

Yes, it is. You should query [Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html):

```
select * from performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage
where object_schema = 'your_schema'
```

The count_star column show how many times each index was used since MySQL was started. If you add the following, you got the never used indexes:

```
and count_star = 0
```

Comment: Valid for mySQL version 5.5.3 or better and only if enabled in my.cnf
see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html

Comment: You just made my day. I was learning about MongoDB and saw they have this feature and had to check if MySQL did as well. Lets just say i have some cleanup to do.

Answer (score 17):

Addition to @user1970667's answer, you may also use:

```
select * from sys.schema_unused_indexes;
```

to get a list of unused indexes.

Comment: Note: I guess its apparent but - `This view is most useful when the server has been up and processing long enough that its workload is representative.`. I guess the same applies when querying `performance_schema`

Comment: Yup.  Production servers run for a long time without a restart.